# Tint sequence of sprites using Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to figure out best method to tint sequence of sprites.
It is simple to tint one sprite using `setColor` or `CCTintTo`.

I have spritesheet which contains 20 frames for 5 animations. Every time my character changes its color, it means that I want to see all next frames painted in new color.

Should I set color to whole spritesheet? But in this case need to store character sprites in separate spritesheet will emerge.

__

Here is my solution but seems that I'm doing it wrong :)

https://gist.github.com/4634157

(zoomed animation just for example of sprite-based animation)

Comment: you can't tint a spritesheet (CCSpritebatchnode). If you use CCAnimate or setdisplayframe the sprite retains its current color, no problem there.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am using 7 sprites for 1 character and I can't believe that I have to manually repaint every frame (that means 7*20) when I want to change color. Does that mean I need to use palette swap technique?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Guess I'm doing it wrong? https://gist.github.com/4634157 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to indexed textures and palette-swap akin technique (using fragment shaders). Simple and scalable solution.